# Java Sockets and Server-Client Issues

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, client-server, client

No two systems are the same(especially in networking) which may make your results different than mine, but I'm having some trouble with getting my Java Server and my Java Client to play nice with eachother. Take a look:

Server:

```
package ca.xeyler;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ChatServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ChatServer server = new ChatServer();
    server.run();
}

public void run() throws Exception {
    ServerSocket SRVSOCK = new ServerSocket(444);
    Socket SOCK = SRVSOCK.accept();
    InputStreamReader IR = new InputStreamReader(SOCK.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR);

    String MESSAGE = BR.readLine();
    System.out.println(MESSAGE);

    if(MESSAGE != null) {
        PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(SOCK.getOutputStream());
        PS.println("Hello");
    }
}

}
```

Client:

```
package ca.xeyler;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Chat {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Chat CLIENT = new Chat();
    CLIENT.run();
}

public void run() throws Exception {
    Socket SOCK = new Socket("localhost", 444);
    PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(SOCK.getOutputStream());
    PS.println("Hi, server!");

    InputStreamReader IR = new InputStreamReader(SOCK.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR);

    String MESSAGE = BR.readLine();
    System.out.println(MESSAGE);
}

}
```

And, the most important part, the issues:

Server Issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Resource temporarily unavailable: recv failed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at ca.xeyler.ChatServer.run(ChatServer.java:19)
at ca.xeyler.ChatServer.main(ChatServer.java:10)
```

Client Issue:

```
null
```

You guys are great. Thanks in advance for solving my derpy problems!

Comment: `null` from `readLine()` just means end of stream. No mystery there. Server issue is strange. You should definitely use a higher port, above 1024: try 4444 for example.

Comment: Well, apparently, on port 24342, It still won't work. Same error messages, so I'm willing to bet that changing the port didn't do much...